# Validación a través de middleware en Express

Tags: nodejs, express

Estoy realizando una API Rest en Nodejs con Express y MongoDB. Se le permite al usuario invitar a otro usuario para que participe en un tablero (similar a Trello). Lo que quiero es registrar un nuevo colaborador para ese tablero.

Esquema colaborador:

```
let Colaborador = new Schema({
user:{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
    require: [true, "El usuario es requerido"]
},

role:{
    type: Number,
    require: [true, "El rol es requerido"]
},

tablero:{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Tablero',
    require: [true, "El Tablero es requerido"]
}
})
```

Como el usuario conoce el email del otro usuario que quiere que colabore en el tablero, necesito obtener la ID a partir del email que este conoce, por lo tanto, había pensado en crear un middleware para que valide el email y retorne la id del nuevo colaborador, de la siguiente forma:

```
let ValidarEmail = (req, res, next)=>{

    if(!req.body.email){
        res.status(400).json({
            ok:false,
            message: "El email en necesario"
        })
    }

    User.find({email: req.body.email})
    .then(user=>{
        if(!user){
            res.status(404).json({
                ok:false,
                message: "El usuario no existe"
            })
        }

        req.colaborator = user['_id']

        next();

    })
    .catch(err=>{
        res.status(500).json({
            ok:false,
            err
        })
    })

}
```

Quería saber si es correcto realizar esto en un middleware o seria correcto realizarlo directamente en el controlador

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta bien delegar cada uno de los trabajos en este caso es bueno, además podrías crear otro middleware aparte, que validará si el correo ingresado es valido incluso podrías poner la primera parte de tu función en esta otra función

```
function esCorreoValido(req, res, next) {
  if(!req.body.email){
    return res.status(400).json({
      ok:false,
      message: "El email en necesario"
    })
  }
  // Validar correo aquí
}
```

Después podrías tener otro middleware que valida si el correo electrónico ingresado existe (este se ejecutaría solo si el de arriba ejecuta `next()`)

```
function existeCorreoEnDB() {
    User.find({email: req.body.email})
    .then(user=>{
        if(!user){
            res.status(404).json({
                ok:false,
                message: "El usuario no existe"
            })
        }

        req.colaborator = user['_id']

        next();

    })
    .catch(err=>{
        res.status(500).json({
            ok:false,
            err
        })
    })
}
```

El primer middleware te ayudaría a validar el correo en cualquier llamada en la que necesites verificar que efectivamente es valido (por ejemplo en el registro y en este caso en agregar tablero) además esto te permite tener a cada función haciendo una única cosa.

En definitiva si es buena tu idea, la razón del controlador es que este haga solamente de enlace por lo que mientras menos responsabilidad tenga mejor, pues la data ya debe venir filtrada antes de que este pueda enviarla como respuesta por ejemplo.

Comment: Gracias Eladio, voy a separar mi middleware para tener la validacion de email previamente.

Comment: En tu función middleware `esCorreoValido`, cuando haces la evaluación condicional (`if(!req.body.email)){ ... }` es necesario devolver la respuesta usando la sentencia `return`, de lo contrario la función seguirá ejecutándose. Saludos

Comment: Gracias @MauricioContreras por la observación!

Comment: Tienes razón corregido